# Try to bind partial view for different classes

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, model-binding

I try to use one partial view for all classes implementing particular interface

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentItem", Model.RentItem);}

@{Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentItem", Model.EquipmentItem);}

@{Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentItem", Model.InterestItem);}

@{Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentItem", Model.ForfeitItem);}

@{Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentItem", Model.SupplyItem);}
```

All PaymentItems are part of the model. After I post the page all payment items bind the values from the last rendered partial view. I assume the problem is that the partial view generates same ids and names for each invoke. How can i bypass this ?
Thanks in advance, I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Please read [aks] and realize we can't look at your screen. What does _"After I post the page all payment items bind the values from the last rendered partial view"_ mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that all class that are part of my model has identical value after bind and passing to the action method in controller.

Comment: Yes, they retain their posted values through the ModelState.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting your model properties to the particular interface?

**EDIT:**

What I mean is to specify the model

e.g.

> @model IViewM

on the first line of your *_PaymentItem* file.